# Problem with plugin referencing to a joint

Tags: gazebo, xacro

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I made a gazebo plugin which simulates a particular motor. To do this I created this plugin which inherits from a ModelPlugin, and I take the joint from a model class.
If there is a single joint it's ok, but if there are two or more joints, I need to give a reference to the plugin. As this [link](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins) suggests I used the reference name of the joint in the gazebo tag.

```
<joint name="joint1" type="revolute">
<parent link="link1"/>
<child link="link2"/>
<origin xyz="0 ${width} ${height1 - axel_offset}" rpy="0 ${PI} 0"/> 
<limit lower="${-1.5*PI}" upper="${1.5*PI}" velocity="${2*PI}" effort="220"/> 
<axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
<dynamics damping="0.7"/>
<spring_stiffness>2300</spring_stiffness>
</joint>

<gazebo reference="joint1">
<plugin name="motor_spring" filename="/home/gabriele/gazebo_plugin_tutorial/build/libmotor_spring_plugin.so">
    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
</plugin>
</gazebo>
```

The compilation is ok, but when I try to start gazebo I see this warning:

```
Warning [parser.cc:713] XML Element[plugin], child of element[joint] not defined in SDF. Ignoring[plugin]. You may have an incorrect SDF file, or an sdformat version that doesn't support this element.
```

Do I wrong in positioning the gazebo tag in my xacro file? Do I wrong to use a ModelPlugin type?
If there are more joint that uses the plugin, there is another way to do it?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13180/problem-with-plugin-referencing-to-a-joint./) by [gabri89](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2451/gabri89/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 19 on 2016-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

A `ModelPlugin` can't be attached to a `<joint>`; it must be attached to the `<model>`. Perhaps you can add a parameter to your `<plugin>` that takes the name of the joint to use for the motor?

I realize that the tutorial you referenced is wrong. I've created [an issue about fixing the tutorial](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_tutorials/issues/55/fix-tutorial-about-attaching-plugins-to).

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2016-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2